# what are the advantages of having strong gluteus muscles in martial arts?

Tags: training, karate, mixed-martial-arts, kumite

Does strong gluteus muscle strength give the pro athletes an edge out there? Maybe I can rearrange my training schedule for the next karate competition.And I had an injury before and had to work my gluteus muscles. Perhaps there is a distinct advantage to having strong glutes or glutes over the competition. Maybe this also motivates me to train harder. I want to focus on agility and speed. Maybe in the future when I want to try other martial arts this knowledge will be very useful for my performance as well.

Comment: Welcome to Martial Arts Stackexchange! Can you, please, give a more context for your question? I see, that you are interested, but maybe question would be better, if supported with some your expirience/knowledge as pro (or counter) argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For karate, important uses of the gluteus muscles include:

- explosively closing distance, particularly when the back leg is bent and the knee
  is turned forward, so you can think of the back leg contributing
  something akin to a sprinter pushing over the starting block,
- delivering a strong, explosive jab or reverse punch (the glutes will
  tend to contract on the same side as the punching arm), and
- any kick
  that drags the leg from the open/chest side of the body towards your
  back, such as a downward or sideways heel or hooking kick (kake geri, ura mawashi geri, kakato geri),
- one type of side thrusting kick - https://youtu.be/uTtyTOLqnoc?t=262 - (which is not done much in traditional karate, but involves the kicking leg's knee extending linearly from somewhere near the chest towards the target); by way of contrast - the yoko geri kekomi I practiced as part of kyokushin karate has completely different knee preparation and the hip rotating in the opposite direction - like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pye797lkisI